# Sort API call response with js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

After I request some data with an API call, I want to sort this data. The call returns the following structure:

```
var values =[ 
    {id: 1, type: "Gas", name: "G1,6", contractedPower: "2.5"}, 
    {id: 2, type: "Gas", name: "G10", contractedPower: "2.5"},
    {id: 3, type: "Gas", name: "G2,6", contractedPower: "2.5"}, 
    {id: 4, type: "Gas", name: "G100", contractedPower: "2.5"}, 
    {id: 5, type: "Electricity", name: "1X4A", contractedPower: "0.8"},
    {id: 6, type: "Electricity", name: "1X6A", contractedPower: "0.8"},
    {id: 7, type: "Electricity", name: "1X10A", contractedPower: "0.8"}, ....]
```

I've tried sorting it using the following algorithm:

```
var PhysicalCapacities = [];
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
  if (values[i].type == type){
      PhysicalCapacities.push(values[i]);
  }
}
var sortedArray = _(PhysicalCapacities).chain().sortBy(function(PhysicalCapacity) {
      return PhysicalCapacity.name;}).value();
```

This algorithm first filters out the ones with the right type. Then, it sorts it by the name value. The only problem is, it sorts them in a semi-right order:

For gas:

> G1,6, G10, G100, G2,6

While it should be:

> G1,6, G2,6, G10, G100

And for electricity:

> 1x10A, 1X4A, 1X6A

While it should be:

> 1X4A, 1X6A, 1X10A

Does anyone know how to tweak it so it will give it back in the order I want it to be?

Comment: what are the rules, why is `G10` before `G2,6`? At the moment your just sorting alphabetically so thats why they appear in that order. I think you just want to sort by the value before the comma and ignore the value after the comma?

Comment: Well, you are comparing *strings*, so `G100` is indeed smaller than `G2`. If you want to parse them using other logic, you should use that in your callback. Say, for gas, you could strip the starting `G` and parse the rest as a number, so you'd get `100` after `2`. For electricity, you might need to do something more complex

Comment: The numbers represent how big it is, so G2,6 should be smaller than G10. I guess I could strip off the G like @vlaz suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should do this:

1. to replace letter of the key "name"
2. replace the comma for dot
3. convert the number in float
4. sort the array

Like this:

```
var PhysicalCapacities = [];
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
  if (values[i].type == type){
     PhysicalCapacities.push(values[i]);
  }
 }

var sortedArray = _(PhysicalCapacities).chain().sortBy(function(PhysicalCapacity) {
  return parseFloat(PhysicalCapacity.name.replace(/[^0-9$.,]/g, '').replace(',','.'));
}).value();
```